# ARM asssembler: rotation of bits in immediate value

Tags: arm, assembly, assembler

Consider

```
MVN r3,#0xFFFF807F
```

Is this an invalid instruction from ARM?
Since MVN is simply the complement, it equates to

```
MOV r3, #0x00007F80
```

In this case, won't it be valid since I can just rotate 0x7F8 right by 4 bits? Why is this invalid?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello Meep, I am just curious and throwing an opinion. How is the "rotate" related to MVN (The MVN instruction takes the value of Operand2, performs a bitwise logical NOT operation on the value, and places the result into Rd.)? Could the "invalid" due to the register size, if you are assembling in "Thumb extension, 16bit"?

Comment: The compiler is saying it is invalid.  Is this your first programming language, since your questions are very basic?  Assessembler is not a good language to learn how to program.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Especially on an ARM. If you want assembler pick something like oldest, smallest, simplest PICs or a PicoBlaze.

Comment: @jay some ARM instructions allow immediate operands which are listed as 32 bit values in the source, but are encoded as an 8 bit value and a number of bits to shift (rotate) the value.

Comment: What is your target architecture and instruction set? There are quite a few variations on what is or isn't possible depending on that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I assumed (incorrectly) it was immediate loading operation. Keep working on it! You will need it to handle the deepest area of the coding. I have no doubt you will challenge RTOS next round.

Comment: I found this, [Load immediate values](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/writing-arm-assembly-language/load-immediate-values), if you need. Meantime, thanks to @jcaron for the help !

Comment: Meep, you okay? Hope everything is going okay for you. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that the instruction is invalid because in a “flexible second operand” as required by `MOV`/`MVN`, an immediate value must be able to be expressed as an **8 bit** pattern shifted by an **even** number of bits.

Your pattern does not match both requirements. Taking the complemented value (0x7f80), it is either 8 bits shifted by an odd number of bits (0xff shifted 7 bits) or at least a 9 bit pattern.

See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-general-data-processing-instructions/Flexible-second-operand?lang=en for details

Note however that details may vary depending on the exact dialect (Thumb, ARM...). On ARMv6T2 and above, `MOV` can take any 16-bit value, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

There's a barrel shifter in front of operand 2 to the ALU. On these instructions, it is encoded this way:

[image]

(Picture from [here](http://csbio.unc.edu/mcmillan/Media/arm-instructionset.pdf).)

Note that there are only ***four*** rotate bits, not five. So this field is multiplied by 2 to get the actual 32-bit barrel shifter rotation.

Now, look at your constant and ask yourself if there is any possible way to rotate an 8-bit value by 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, or 30 bits to get your constant. Yes or no? Any possible way?

Since it cannot encode the constant in this fashion, you get an error.

That's all.

Comment: Actually, it is a feature of the assembler to replace a MOV with a MOVN or vice-versa (and similarly for other pairs of instructions) if it can be encoded that way and not the way it was originally written. But even replacing the MOVN by a MOV does not allow encoding the value as 8 bits + even shift.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks!! So I'm actually wrong here? Or does this rule not apply in the case of the MVN and I'm "accidentally" right?

Comment: @jcaron Could you expand your answer a bit to incorporate more detail? I'd appreciate it and I'd learn from you, I think. I'm just reading docs on a processor I've never used. It would make it easy for me to just remove my contribution, too. (Feel free to use my diagram and reference.) I'd rather someone with some experience in ARM provide more complete details.

Comment: The part about "is there any possible way to..." is right, there's no way to encode the value given, whether the original one (0xFFFF807F) or the complemented one (0x00007F80). The part which is incorrect is when you say it will not recode to a different instruction, when the docs say otherwise. Never coded ARM assembly myself either, just read the docs like you :-)

Comment: @jcaron Thanks. I'll correct what I wrote. But meanwhile feel free to improve/expand. I'll back off to a better description. I want the best for the OP, if possible, and not two different answers if they don't add anything to each other.

Comment: Hopefully someone with actual ARM assembler experience will be able to chime in

Comment: @jcaron Totally agree with that!